# Downloading files with w3m

Tags: w3m

I'm trying to acess my emails attachements using ̀`w3m`. When doing so, I managed to see the attachement content. However,  I have no clue on how to have this file downloaded on my computer, wich is my main purpose.

Any ideas how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the address of the file you should be able to do

```
wget address
```

If you have authentication issues try:

```
wget --http-user=USER --http-password=PASSWORD address
```

This may work depending on how the log-in is handled on the server side.

Comment: I can access it while being logged in, but I don't see a way to do so with wget (trying to access the adress via wget redirects me elsewhere).

Comment: It is worth trying to send the wget request with the following options: `--http-user=USER  --http-password=PASSWORD` (see edit above) it depends how the website handles the log in though.

Comment: I'll look into it, but is not `w3m` able do download files ?